# WordPress Ajax & PHP Email Issues - No Data in email

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been struggling with getting data to be sent on a large work inquiry form on a site I'm working on.

**Quick User Story:**

As a site owner I want to have users submit data via checkboxes and some enter some personal information. When clicking the submit button I want to send the data via Ajax and also submit to WordPress built in AJAX functionality. That data needs to be emailed back to me.

**Where I'm at**

I have AJAX being submitted and an email delivery taking place. Where I'm stumped is why there is no data coming through on my form/ajax request.

**HTML**

```
<form id="inquire" class="form" name="inquireForm">
... a crap ton of checkboxes and a few inputs for name,email etc...
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

The function below is fired via a jQuery Validate library. There is a submitHandler method where the follow is called within.

```
function submitForm() {
    /* Keep form from submitting normally*/
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Clear success div*/
    $('.success_box').addClass('hidden').removeClass('error').html('');

    var cleanData = $('#inquire').serialize();
    var form = cleanData;

    $.ajax({
        url: myInquiry.ajaxurl,
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            action: "send_inquiry",
            form: form,
            nonce: myInquiry.nonce
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(' The sever responded: ', data , textStatus , jqXHR);
            if (textStatus == "success") {
                $('.success_box').removeClass('hidden').html('<p>Success! Your message has been sent. We will reach you to you in less than 24 hours.</p>');
                fadeModal();               
            } else {
                $('.success_box').removeClass('hidden').addClass('error').html('<p>Error! Your message has not been sent.</p>');
            }
        },
    });
}
```

**functions.php**

```
// enqueue ajax scripts
wp_enqueue_script('ajax_script', get_template_directory_uri(). '/assets/js/dist/inquire.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
wp_localize_script( 'ajax_script', 'myInquiry', 
    array( 
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "send_inquiry_nonce" ),
    )
);

// add in WP actions with unique names that match
add_action( 'wp_ajax_send_inquiry', 'send_inquiry_process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_send_inquiry', 'send_inquiry_process' );

// Try to send email
function send_inquiry_process() {
    $user_email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $headers = "From: " . " $user_email" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-to: ". $user_email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0". "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $to = "andy@example.com";
    $subject = "New Inquiry!";
    $message = "It works";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

**The Result**

The result of this so far is a solid Ajax posting, I do get an email, but the `$user_email` PHP variable for instance returns undefined. That said all data from the form I try to return is nil.

My staging server is on Digital Ocean. It appears the mail method in PHP works but I'm not 100% sure if its a server issue or not at this point.

**Nice to haves**

I'm hoping the returned data can be formatted as HTML. I just need to write a table and include the variables for the mail message. Before that happens I need to it work! I have the charset to UTF-8 currently so I'm assuming all is good.

**ALSO**

I realize there are huge security flaws all over this. I'm going to focus on that but again it needs to work first.

Any insight you can provide would make my day! I'm stressing hard. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see you accessing a `$_POST` key of `form`,  `data` in your Ajax is `$_POST` in php so  `$_POST['action']` is `data.action` .  `data.email` doesn't exist.  Maybe  `data.form.email` does so it would be `$_POST['form']['email']` - make sense?

Answer (score 0):

As I put in comments your data in ajax is sent like this

```
data: {
  action: "send_inquiry",
  form: form,
  nonce: myInquiry.nonce
},
```

In PHP ( if I see it right ) it would be like this

```
 $_POST = [
     'action' => "send_inquiry",
     'form'  =>  [...],
    'nonce'  => '..' /// what ever this is myInquiry.nonce
 ];
```

So then trying to access `$_POST['email']`  is not going to work, you need

```
   $_POST['from']['email'];
```

Instead.  To be sure you could print out the post array with `var_dump` this is a bit harder to do -via- AJAX though.  But `data` is what you are "posting" to the backend, not `form`.

Unless WordPress does some Mojo behind the scene, TBH I haven't done much AJAX though WordPress, so I could be completely off base.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This definitely makes sense only now it's returning a random character as the  "x"@email.com which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The issue was with the way I was parsing the data. You can't have an `action:` call on the `$.ajax` method.

So switching this:

```
function submitForm() {

/* Keep form from submitting normally*/
event.preventDefault();

/* Clear success div*/
$('.success_box').addClass('hidden').removeClass('error').html('');

var cleanData = $('#inquire').serialize();
var form = cleanData;


$.ajax({
    url: myInquiry.ajaxurl,
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      action: "send_inquiry",
      form: form,
      nonce: myInquiry.nonce
    },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        console.log(' The sever responded: ', data , textStatus , jqXHR);

        if (textStatus == "success") {
       $('.success_box').removeClass('hidden').html('<p>Success! Your message    has been sent. We will reach you to you in less than 24 hours.</p>');
       fadeModal();               
     } else {
        $('.success_box').removeClass('hidden').addClass('error').html('<p>Error! Your message has not been sent.</p>');
   }
   },
});
```

To this:

```
function submitForm() {

/* Keep form from submitting normally*/
event.preventDefault();

/* Clear success div*/
$('.success_box').addClass('hidden').removeClass('error').html('');

var cleanData = $('#inquire').serialize();
var data = cleanData;


$.ajax({
   url: myInquiry.ajaxurl,
   type: "POST",
   data: data + '&action=send_inquiry',
   dataType: 'JSON',
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   console.log(' The sever responded: ', data , textStatus , jqXHR);
      if (textStatus == "success") {
       $('.success_box').removeClass('hidden').html('<p>Success! Your message has been sent. We will reach you to you in less than 24 hours.</p>');
      fadeModal();               
   } else {
           $('.success_box').removeClass('hidden').addClass('error').html('<p>Error! Your message has not been sent.</p>');
    } 
   },
});
```

Did the trick. I updated the `data` variable to blatantly be `data`(for preference sake) and on `data:` within the ajax call I returned `data + &action=send_query`. That made the POST update to what I needed to send the data through to the PHP email script.

If that wasn't clear feel free to reach out!